# Run shell script/start Junit test in android without PC /from SD card

Tags: android, linux, shell

I have a Robotium Test case, which is an instrumental `JUnit` test case, and I can run it from the command line from my PC using the following shell script:

```
adb shell am instrument -w android.support.v7.appcompat.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

However as we know the Android Linux system doesn't have a terminal installed. Is there a way I can get the device to recognize/run the shell script? Cannot be an external program that I have to manually click, the file or the test case is to be called from an App.

Any help is much appreciated, including raw ideas that I can just look into. Thanks again to anyone who provides assistance.

Answer (score 2):

We have a well documented Blog post on the exact stuff you are looking for : Please have a look:

http://mindfiremobiletesting.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/robotium-run-test-scripts-directly-from-mobile-device-way-to-run-shell-scripts-on-mobile-device/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however I cant have step 5, there cannot be any manual steps in my implementation.  By any chance, do you know how to call a specific test case for a specific package using InstrumentationTestRunner class within an App?